# Set value inside script tag with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script for stripe,

```
<script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_**"
    data-amount="2000"
    // ...
</script>
```

I want to be able to change the value of data-amount to a JavaScript variable for variable prices I have a set of radio buttons that will set the amount the user wants to a js variable I need to pass that to this script code.

Here's an example of the jq code that processes the radio buttons.

```
if($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val() == "2500"){
    var pricecheck =  $('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val();
}
```

Basically I need var price check to set data-amount in the first script.

Comment: Have you tried `$("script").data("amount", pricecheck)`? Or `$("script").attr("data-amount", pricecheck)` if you need to change it in DOM. Also need to make sure you are selecting script tag you want.

Comment: @phpcoderx, I don't think so.

Comment: @phpcoderx no it didn't.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov Either I'm not using the code right or it didn't work. 
I added an id to the script and used it like this 
$("varcheck").attr("data-amount", pricecheck)
in the if statement

Comment: @Craptasitc, you should select id this way:  `$("#varcheck").attr("data-amount", pricecheck)`. I have just tested it in browser and it works just fine. But I still don't understand why do you need to set attribute value to script tag. By the way jQuery 1.9 or higher, not sure about elder versions.